# Having trouble updating the statusBar in PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, statusbar

I am new to PyQt4 and am trying to allow my program to set a different message on the statusbar ad different times throughout the program, but I can't ever seem to get any text to appear on it.

The GUI was designed in Qt Designer, in the file generated by pyuic, It gives me:

```
self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
```

Inside the setupUI Function.

When I call `self.ui.statusBar.showMessage('Ready')` It returns:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'showMessage'
```

But when I call:

```
    self.ui.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')
```

I get no errors, but the statusbar remains blank and does not display "Ready".

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong or missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not calling statusBar.
With `self.statusBar.showMessage('Ready')`, you are calling the showMessage attribute of the statusBar method.
You should use `self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')`, where you get the status bar calling the statusBar method.

Comment: I fixed a typo in my code above. When I call "self.ui.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')" Nothing happens.